# Is it possible to have a CallOut content being created without calling open()

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4, flex4.5

I need to access the initial selection of a component that is accessible through a CallOut.

Is it possible to initialize this component without having to call an initial open. Some kind of creationPolicy.

```
<s:Callout id="callout" creationPolicy="all">
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:DateSpinner id="dt" minDate="{new Date(2000,01,01)}" selectedDate="{new Date()}"
                       maxDate="{new Date(2014,11,31)}" change="changeHandler(event)"/>
    </s:VGroup>  
</s:Callout>
```

Comment: Can you show in code where is your problem exactly? 
Note that there are only 'auto' and 'none' creation policies. Also both datespinner and vgroup are created after creation complete is dispatched ( if I set creation policy to 'auto' ). So you are able to  work with them.

Comment: @Daniil Moskovtsov There is no problem on my code. But when I try to access the DateSpinner(dt) initially it's null. It is just when I called the open method of the Callout at least once that it is instantiated.

Comment: have you tried to use a callLater()?  I've run into the problem before where I needed to access components that didn't exist yet.  Once everything is created, the callLater kicks in and voila, your component is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Please have look the component. May you get any help out of it

http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/tourdeflex/web/#docIndex=-1;illustIndex=0

Go to the link & search for "callout"

Comment: Thanks that is where I looked in the first place. There is nothing there about instantiating the CallOut content on Creation of its parent View.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can create the content by calling `initialize()` and `createDeferredContent()` on the callout.

```
callOut.initialize();
callOut.createDeferredContent();
```

You may need to call this code on the creation complete event in the document where the call out is defined.